# Additional method JQuery validation with German special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I would like to use JQuery Validation to validate a text input field for text input. But with spaces and the german special characters (äöüß).

For this I have created an additional method "letterspecial":

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("letterspecial", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0196\u0228\u0214\u0246\u0220\u0252\u0223]+$/.test(value);
}, "Letters only please with Special Charts and Spaces allow");
```

I'm pretty sure it's the RegEx, however I don't know how to set it correctly.

But maybe there is another solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `äöüß` in your regex, no need for escaped unicode characters, as far as I can tell :

```js
const regex = /^[a-zA-Zäöüß]+$/;

console.log(regex.test("üßeörgä"))
console.log(regex.test("héhé this is invalid hôhô"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed the code to: return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Zäöüß ]*$/.test(value); give me the same error Message.

Comment: What? What error message? You didn't mention that, that's the most important information

Comment: Sorry, that was probably my mistake and was related to the browser cache. Now it works. Thanks a lot